# posting in multiple divs randomly or in order

Tags: php, ajax, html, post

Suppose I have an HTML form with a submit button (consider the example of facebook wall post form)

Now suppose I have 3 divs side by side of equal width and auto height under the form.

My question is:

Can I display the posts randomly among the 3 divs below? Like the 1st post goes into the 1st div then the 2nd maybe in the 3rd div and so on.

In order will also suffice, like 1st post in 1st div, 2nd in 2nd, 3rd and 3rd and s forth.

I am using `AJAX` post with `PHP` backend.

I tried assigning a random number between 1 and 3 to each post which would be stored in the database.
but the problem is right from the 2nd post onwards the posts start getting multiplied since the entire database table is read on page load.

I mean to say suppose the 1st post enters in the 2nd div then the 2nd post which gets a value 3 assigned enters in the 3rd div but the catch is that along with it there's a copy of the 1st post also in the 3rd div.

I hope you understand. Can someone help me out? providing an example will be most appreciated...

Comment: Please ask your question in proper format...what`s your need?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you're meaning something like that.
http://jsbin.com/eduyum/1/edit

When you first load the page, you need to prefill the array that holds all the posts.
(not included in code sample)

Comment: this is not wht i want! no lists within unordered list! I want to post to show in 3 separate divs randomly

Comment: What's the difference if you're using list items in a list, or divs inside a container div? It's pretty easy to change the code in the demo, though. Just exchange the `ul` with a `div` and the `li` with a div.